# How to query the object and its children to JSON?

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my model I have, for now, 3 classes:

- **Quest**: Basics attributes of quest
- **GoToAndAnswer**: Kinda type of a quest, which extends **Quest**
- **SeekAndAnswer**: Same as above, extending **Quest**

I'm using Django to build an API so in my View I want to print the info about these Quests in JSON format. The problem is I don't know how to serialize the objects correctly (Im really new at Django and Python):

```
# Only get the attributes of the class Quest, obviously
serializers.serialize("json", Quest.objects.all())

# Only get the atributes of the GoToAndAnswer, nothing about the Quest attributes
serializers.serialize("json", GoToAndAnswer.objects.all())
```

So which is the best way to achieve this?

I have seen posts like this: [JSON Serialization of a Django inherited model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866105/json-serialization-of-a-django-inherited-model)

But it didnt help...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Django REST Framework which solves all your problems.

That's a Django app with a excellent documentation and all the tools you need to create a API. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/